# Execute an async Task, change a control's value which fires an event

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, dispatcher

I have a loading method which runs asynchronously.
Inside this method, I change the Checked-State of a RadioButton.

This works fine and it doesn't matter if I execute it directly or via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

However, the RadioButton has a "CheckedChanged"-Event. When I call

```
Dispatcher.Invole((Action)()=>{rb.IsChecked=true;}));
```

I would expect my asynchronous method to wait for the checked changed event (which runs an async method again) being done.

In the attached code you will see that the execution-order is:

1. "BeginInvoke"
2. "EndInvoke"
3. "RbChanged"

What I would like to have is:

1. "BeginInvoke"
2. "RbChanged"
3. "EndInvoke"

Any options for this?

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async enter code herevoid Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await RightAfterLoading();
        }


        private async Task RightAfterLoading()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("BeginInvoke");
            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { rb.IsChecked = true; }));
            Debug.WriteLine("EndInvoke");
        }

        private async void rb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await SomethingAfterChecked();
        }

        private async Task SomethingAfterChecked()
        {
            string abc = string.Empty;
            await Task.Run(() => abc = "RbCheckedChanged");
            Console.WriteLine(abc);
        }
```

And MainWindow.xaml looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncAwaitIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AsyncAwaitIssue"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rb"
                     Checked="rb_Checked"
                     Content="CheckedOrNot"
                     IsChecked="False" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the very nature of `async void` methods.  When you set `IsChecked` it *will* wait for the event handler for the changed event to execute, but when you execute that handler all you ever do is *start* an asynchronous operation.  The handler will complete before those asynchronous operations have finished.

Ideally you'd avoid such a situation.  If you have something that needs to happen after the work you're doing in the changed event, it'd be better if that change event would perform that operation.  If you can't, you'd need to manually create some form of communication between these sections of code and couple these operations together fairly tightly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Servy.

Comment: I was expecting an answer like this, but I wanted to see if there was a solution for this. However, we will need to find another way to work around this "issue".